# How to compare adjacent elements in 2D array if duplicate?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have a 2D array:

```
var arr1 = [["Egypt","Grid",50],["Egypt","Grid",10],["Nigeria","Grid",20],["Ghana","Grid",60],["Egypt","Grid",30]]
```

I want to check the first element of each array, e.g. Egypt, Nigeria and Ghana to see if they are duplicates. But I only want it to check against the next element not against all elements in the array. If one or more elements are duplicated next to each other, I want to return one array summing the elements at position 2 (50,10,20,60,30)

This should result in :

```
var arr2 = [["Egypt","Grid",60],["Nigeria","Grid",20],["Ghana","Grid",60]],["Egypt","Grid",30]]
```

Note how even though there are 3 arrays with "Egypt", it only combines where they are next to each other.

I have tried both `map` and `for loop` but don't have anything that is close to working. This is what I've started with:

```
arr1.map(function (unit, index, array) {
var length = array.length
if (index < length - 2) {
  var next = array[index + 1][0]
  if (unit[0] === next) {
    }
  }
})
```

This works to check if elements are duplicates. I think I need to next put the duplicates into a separate array which I can then `reduce` but am not sure how to do that. Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement) loop iterating over each array except the last and checking if the first element of the current iterated element matches the first element of current+1.

If they match, sum the third elements of each and assign to the current iterated array, delete `current+1` (here using [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)) and decrement `i` to recheck the same index again.

```js
var arr1 = [
  ['Egypt', 'Grid', 50],
  ['Egypt', 'Grid', 10],
  ['Nigeria', 'Grid', 20],
  ['Ghana', 'Grid', 60],
  ['Egypt', 'Grid', 30],
];

for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length - 1; i++) {
  if (arr1[i][0] === arr1[i + 1][0]) {
    arr1[i][2] = arr1[i][2] + arr1[i + 1][2];
    arr1.splice(i + 1, 1);
    i--;
  }
}

console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: This answer provided the simplest and most flexible solution to my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `grouping` array and in which you only push the element if an only if the last elments `country` and `category` doesn't match with the last element in the `grouping` array or if there is no element  in the `grouping`

You can use `for..of` loop

```js
var arr1 = [
  ["Egypt", "Grid", 50],
  ["Egypt", "Grid", 10],
  ["Nigeria", "Grid", 20],
  ["Ghana", "Grid", 60],
  ["Egypt", "Grid", 30],
];

const grouping = [];

for (let [country, category, num] of arr1) {
  const last = grouping[grouping.length - 1];
  const [lastCountry, lastCategory, lastNum] = last ?? [];

  lastCountry && lastCountry === country && lastCategory === category
    ? (last[2] += num)
    : grouping.push([country, category, num]);
}

console.log(grouping);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `reduce`. For easing the destructuring I have chosen to first *prepend* results to the accumulator to then finally reverse that result with `reverse`:

```js
let arr = [["Egypt","Grid",60],["Nigeria","Grid",20],["Ghana","Grid",60],["Egypt","Grid",30]];

let result = arr.slice(1).reduce(([[x, y, z], ...acc], [a, b, c]) =>
    a === x && b == y ? [[a, b, z + c], ...acc]
                      : [[a, b, c], [x, y, z], ...acc]
, [arr[0]]).reverse();

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You could `reduceRight()` and seed with `arr.pop()` avoiding the slice and the reverse

Comment: `arr.pop()` would mutate the original array, which would be a pitty. But otherwise it is a nice idea.

Comment: True, I suppose `.slice(0, -1).reduceRight( ... [arr.[arr.length-1]]);` then.

Comment: Yes, that would be it then.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr1 = [
            ["Egypt","Grid",50],
            ["Egypt","Grid",10],
            ["Egypt","Grid",10],
            ["Nigeria","Grid",20],
            ["Nigeria","Grid",20],
            ["Nigeria","Grid",20],
            ["Nigeria","Grid",20],
            ["Nigeria","Grid",20],
            ["Ghana","Grid",60],
            ["Egypt","Grid",30]
           ];

var i=0;
var j=1;
while (j<arr1.length){
  if (arr1[i][0] === arr1[j][0]){
    arr1[i][2] += arr1[j][2];
    arr1.splice(j,1);
    continue
  }
  i++;
  j++;
}

console.log(arr1)
```